# Is there any tool for converting flex 3/3.5 project to flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, migration

I am seriously looking for some good tool to avoid the labor work.

I read the [article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex3and4_differences.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader) which mearly has the list of differences and it has guide to migrating flex 3 project to flex 4 even this talks just about manual migration.

Is labor work inevitable in flex migration?

Comment: In my experience, there's no tool. It's going to be work.

Comment: No tool. Instead of a chore think of it as a good learning opportunity to become familiar with spark.

Comment: Agree with other commentors here, also instead of just doing a machine replacement of certain code constructs you should probably attempt to use the new framework components instead since things do run smoother and are generally better separated in the new framework.  I know with huge applications this may seem unreasonable but it should just be considered a major maintenance update.

Comment: I believe there is some sort of XSLT file out there that will help with migrating the MXML which will be the major concern since so far as I know the AS files won't need to really require any systematic changes (perhaps changes to the interface to particular classes but nothing I know of off hand).  The major things are updating namespace entries adding declarations for non-visual components and updating Script tag namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has answered except commenting, I am adding my own answer based on the commenter s and my experience. Right now, there is no tool available. labor work is inevitable.